# Select elements based on condition LINQ TO XML C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am querying XML using LINQ TO XML. I want to query records based on some conditional check here is my XML below: XML will have multiple Orders each order will be in  I want to select order which has  param node  attribute store value is not null and if exists should be 1 and also order with carton information...

```
    <orders>
        <order>
            <criteria>
                <param name="location">123</param>
                <param name="name">Chicago</param>
                <param name="Store">1</param>
                <param name="Account Number">1212121212</param>
            </criteria>
            <items>
                <item> </item>
                <item> </item>           
            </items>
            <cartons>
                <carton>
                     <size> </size>
                     <weight></weight>
                </carton>
            </cartons>
        </order>
    <Order>
    </Order>
    </orders>
```

I am able to do till this:

```
var result = from item in doc.Descendants("order")
                where item.Element("criteria").Element("param").Attribute("name").Value.Contains("store") == true
                && item.Element("cartons") != null
                select item;"
```

Above works fine if my store (param) attribute is first in the filter node but if I move the store(param) to other position than first it does not filter it

Comment: Okay, that all sounds reasonable - what have you tried so far? Have you looked at the `XElement.Attribute` method, and `XElement.Element`? For example `...Where(x => x.Element("criteria").Elements("param").Any(p => (string) p.Attribute("name") == "Store" && (int) p.Value == 1))`

Comment: Okay,  I have this "   var result =
                    from item in doc.Descendants("order")
                    where item.Element("criteria").Element("param").Attribute("name").Value.Contains("store") == true
                    && item.Element("cartons") != null
                    select item;"

Comment: Please put this into the *question*, and explain what the difference is between what it currently does, and what you *want* it to do.

Comment: I did add that in to my question @JonSkeet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're only looking at *one* `param` element - always the first one, because that's what the `Element` does.

You want to match if *any* of the parameters is a "Store" element with a value of 1, so you want to use the `Any` method and use `Elements` to find all the parameters:

```
var query = from item in doc.Descendants("order")
            where item.Element("criteria").Elements("param")
                      .Any(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Store" &&
                                (int) p == 1)
                  && item.Element("cartons") != null
            select item;
```

The query expression isn't really helping you here - I'd use:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("order")
               .Where(item => item.Element("criteria").Elements("param")
                                  .Any(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Store" &&
                                            (int) p == 1)
                              && item.Element("cartons") != null);
```

Comment: That's an straightforward answer. I don't think he can go wrong using your snippet of code !

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks for the answer... Any function did the trick.. thanks again..!!